# Problem using ogr2ogr to convert postGIS table to personal geodatabase

Tags: postgis, convert, ogr2ogr, personal-geodatabase, odbc

I need to convert a PostGIS table to a personal geodatabase using ogr2ogr. I can convert tables to a shapefile without a problem but whenever I try to convert it to .mdb using the ODBC driver, I get an error. I have got the 64-bit GDAL version and also the 64-bit ODBC driver installed.

This is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ODBC" C:\users\[user]\file.mdb PG:"host=localhost user=[user] dbname=[db] password=[password]" "[tablename]"
```

This is the error I get:

```
ODBC driver failed to create C:\users\[user]\file.mdb
```

Am I using the right command to do this, or am I missing a driver or something?

Comment: Is this the format you are aiming at:
http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html

Answer (score 3):

Per the [docs](http://www.gdal.org/drv_odbc.html):

> Currently the ODBC OGR driver is **read-only**, so new features, tables and datasources cannot normally be created by OGR applications.

Additionally, neither the [PGeo](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html) nor [MDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mdb.html) drivers support creation.

Comment: If you need to create database for ArcGIS you need probably use http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html. GeoPackage might works also http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html.